# Couldn't set-up a SMTP Server

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I made a registration form using "createuserwizard" in asp.net C# and set up mailsettings like below.

```
 <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="userwizard" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/secretfiles/secret.aspx" runat="server" >
    <MailDefinition BodyFileName="register.txt" Subject="Registration Confirmation" From="amrit.enest@gmail.com" />
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

This is my webconfig files settings:

```
<system.net>

    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="PickupDirectoryFromIis"/>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

I settled up a smtp server with following settings in ISS.

E-mail address:
**amrit.enest@gmail.com**

Store email in pickup directory:
**C:\Users\eNest-25\Desktop\emails**

Now when i am registering with a new user,it doesn't send emails from "amrit.enest@gmail.com" to register email id,despite it gives the following error message.

```
**Server Error in '/membership' Application.
Cannot get IIS pickup directory.**
```

Answer (score 0):

just enter your host-credentials should help?

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="amrit.enest@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" userName="yourname" password="yourpass" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
 </system.net>
```

Comment: username and password of sending email has to provide here or not something else?

 <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" userName="yourname" password="yourpass" />

Answer (score 0):

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="amrit.enest@gmail.com">
  <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Users\eNest-25\Desktop\emails"/>
</smtp>
```

Comment: @user1544975. that's because you've pointed the "SpecifiedPickupDirectory" as deliveryMethod. The emails get saved in this folder.